# List of Tuples (key, val), replace all instances in a string where key exists with val

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I know I can do this in an imperative manner pretty easily. What I want to figure out is how to do this in a functional manner. I feel like I should be able to accomplish this with either fold or map but I just can't work it out. Its been a long time since I have had education on functional programming.

Say I have tuples like (arbitrary length):

```
[|("X", 2);("Y", 3)|]
```

And a string like:

```
"X + Y"
```

I want a result of:

```
"2 + 3"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly guessed, you can do this using `fold`:

```
[|("X", 2);("Y", 3)|]
|> Seq.fold (fun (str:string) (orig, repl) -> 
     str.Replace(orig, string repl)) "X + Y"
```

The idea is that we use the string as the state (initial state is "X + Y"). The fold then iterates over all the replacements and, for every replacement, we return a new string. To do that, we replace the `orig` value with the new value `repl`, which is done by `str.Replace(orig, string repl)`.

One thing that makes this tricky is that we need type annotation for `str` in order to call `Replace` (without this, F# would not know that `str` is a string).

Comment: Wow, awesome job. I really need to break out the wizard book again when I get some time. Thanks a lot.